# Why does this laptop adaptor have two metal shields with different thicknesses?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

Yesterday, I opened my laptop adaptor to learn something. First off, faced to this kind of shielding:

[image: image1]

There are two shields that cover the circuit. A thick shield which is covered by a thin shield and there is an insulator between them.

A close-up image of the shields:

[image: image2]

1. Why two shields?
2. Why is one of them thick and the other thin?
3. Are there two grounds?

Edit: Another image from underneath:

[image: image3]

Edit2: The images of the thin shield

[image: image4]

[image: image5]

Comment: The thick, heavy plate isn't a shield, it's a heatsink.

Comment: What do you define as a shield? Have you checked to see if it conducts or is magnetizable?

Comment: @DaveTweed But it has covered the whole of the adaptor circuit except the underneath, though there are several IC that are sticked to the thick cover(or as you say heatsink)

Comment: @DaveTweed I didn't expect to see such a big heatsink that has cover the whole of the circuit even the critical parts such as electrolytic capacitors.

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate that the heatsink will heat up the capacitors, but since the box has no air circulation, they needed to spread the heat as much as possible.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yeah, There is no air circulation or other kind of the air cooling. But why didn't they use it as shield?

Comment: I see one heatsink and zero shields. Please show what you are refering to.

Comment: Use a multimeter to check continuity between the Earth prong, the shield, and the heatsink. Are they all earthed or not?

Comment: @winny Please see Edit2

Comment: The thinn one looks like a heat spreader to me. May have some EMI purpose too.

Comment: You'd expect a heat sink to have fins, but that'd be pointless here because there's no air flow. So it's purpose instead is to conduct the heat towards the chassis so it would then seep through to the outside surface.

Comment: Is this laptop adaptor not fully encased in plastic? Given plastic is a poor conductor of heat, they spread around the heat as much as possible. Then there is a thin-steel magnetic/electric fields shield. Notice there are plenty of openings for the internal fields to emit, and cause EMI/RFI problems. I view these blackbricks as very serious problems for precision measurements.